# HTTP on a HTTPS Website

Tags: http, https

I was just wondering this small little question. I know it is irreverent to coding, but I just had to know quickly.

If you type in `http://` for a `https://` will it still take you to the correct place?

Comment: Depends on DNS and/or .htaccess settings. You can't count on it.

Comment: Thank you! :) I did not know if the web automatically did that... I could add it to my .htaccess though eventually when necessary

Comment: @timgavin: This has nothing to do with DNS. The client would use DNS to resolve a hostname to an IP address to connect to, but the URL dictates the port to connect to. HTTP and HTTPS run on different ports. DNS has no concept of HTTP/S.

Answer (score 4):

That is mostly dependent on the server configuration.  The server has to accept the initial HTTP request and be configured to redirect the client to an appropriate HTTPS url.

That being said, there are some Internet standards related to automating HTTP-to-HTTPS upgrades.  [HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6797) and [Upgrade Insecure Requests](http://www.w3.org/TR/upgrade-insecure-requests/) allow an HTTP/S server to tell clients that it wants them to automatically use HTTPS for all subsequent requests.  If a client visits an HSTS/UIR-enabled server, it will receive a normal HTTP response with additional HSTS/UIR-related headers.  If the client supports HSTS/UIR, it will then know to automatically send all subsequent HTTP requests to that same server using HTTPS, and in the case of UIR also treat any received HTTP URLs as if they were HTTPS URLs.